# PaintCode 2 with UIButtons in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, storyboard, paintcode

I export a StyleKit.h file from PaintCode 2.  It has a class method:

```
+ (UIImage*)myImage;
```

In my storyboard, I have a UIButton, and I want to set the image for UIControlStateNormal to myImage.  In order to do this, I have added a generic Object to storyboard, set the class of the Object to StyleKit, and then created an outlet from the object to the UIButton.  This seems to be correct; however, when I build an run, I get an error. It seems that the implementation of StyleKit automatically calls `setImage:` on the the target of the outlet.  However, you don't call `setImage:` on a UIButton, but rather, you call `setImage:forState:` so it is throwing an unrecognized selector exception.

Can you only use PaintCode 2 with a UIButton in storyboard by subclassing the UIButton and creating a `setImage:` method that sets the image always for `UIControlStateNormal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, PaintCode, Storyboard, and Buttons don't get along.  You can set the button's image via code, but won't be able to connect it in the storyboard.

Comment: Yeah me too.  I've been using PaintCode more and more lately.  It has been a real life saver on my current project.   But there are a few drawbacks.

Comment: UIButton has 2 kinds of images _(foreground and background)_ and 4 basic states _(normal, selected, highlighted, disabled)_, which can be combined _(selected+highlighted, selected+disabled)_. Which one do you want to set?